# Bootstrap grid not spreading throughout the whole screen width

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following code with 1 row 2 columns. However there is a lot of extra space in the margins of screen. Any idea how to fix it pls?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <p class="card-body">This card on the left of the other two cards, with a fixed height and scrolling.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-9">
        <div class="card">
            <p class="card-body">How do you want to ask the question?<p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <p class="card-body">How should students ask the question?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the div with class container.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-md-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <p class="card-body">This card on the left of the other two cards, with a fixed height and scrolling.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
        <p class="card-body">How do you want to ask the question?<p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <p class="card-body">How should students ask the question?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "container" class provides a responsive layout. If you want to use the full width of the screen and not give this up, use the class "container-fluid" instead